# Why is SaveAllAsync() > 0 false in this case?

Tags: c#, database, http, asp.net-web-api, controller

The **SaveAll() method**

```
    public async Task<bool> SaveAll()
    {
        return await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
    }
```

**UpdateSteps method in my Controller**

```
    [HttpPut("{goalId}/steps")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateSteps(int userId, long goalId, IEnumerable<Step> steps)
    {
        if (userId != int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value))
            return Unauthorized();

        var stepsFromRepo = await _repo.GetStepsById(goalId);

        _mapper.Map(steps, stepsFromRepo);

        if (await _repo.SaveAll())
            return NoContent();

        throw new Exception("Updating steps failed");
    }
```

the **if condition is false** and the Exception gets thrown

The mapping works correctly thats why I dont understand why the changes do not get recognized.

Help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_mapper.Map` (I assume you use `AutoMapper`) when working with collection will not match anything by Id and update it.

```
class Order { public int Id { get; set; } }
class OrderDto { public int Id { get; set; } }

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>());
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var targ1 = new Order {Id = 1};
var targ2 = new Order {Id = 2};
var source = new List<Order> { new Order {Id = 1}};
var target = new List<Order> { targ1, targ2 };
mapper.Map(source, target);
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(target.First(o => o.Id == 1), targ1)); // False - not the same object
Console.WriteLine(target.Count()); // 1
```

So I would assume that `await _repo.GetStepsById(goalId)` code returns simple collection of tracked entities (not the tracked collection), and automapper just basically clears it and adds new items which EF (I assume you use it) does not know anything about, so it can't insert or update anything.

You will need to manually update/add/delete all corresponding entries. Or maybe there is nice package for that, but I don't know about it. Maybe [AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore) has such functionality, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, that's the one :)